# Redirecting to a different page when a person enters login details

Tags: java, html, mysql, css, jsp

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>

<html>
<head>

<style>
body{
  background-color:#F5FFFF;
  opacity:0.9;
  filter:alpha(opacity=80);
  }
h1{
  color:#010066;
  font-size:80px;
  text-align:center;
}
h1.underline{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:-20px;
  margin-bottom:40px;
}
h2{
  color:#010066;
  font-size:22px;
  text-align:center;
}

h3{
  color:#010066;
  font-size:14px;
  text-align:center;
}
#cen
{
  color:#010066;
  text-align:center;
}
</style>
  <script>
</head>
<body>
  </p>
<h1 >ERICSSON</h1>
<h1 class="underline"><img src="line.png" align="top" height="10" width="420"></h1>
<br>
<br>
<h3>Please Enter your Login Details!</h3>
<br>
<br> 

<p id='cen'>USERNAME :  <input type="text" name="usr"/>
<br>    
<br>
PASSWORD :  <input type="password" name="pwd" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="LOGIN" id="LOGIN">
</p>

<%
String Username = request.getParameter("usr");
String Password = request.getParameter("pwd");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proj","root","root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select password from login where username = '"+Username+"'");
if (rs1.next())
{
  if(rs1.getString(1).equals(Password))
  {

  }
}
else
{

}
%>enter code here

</body>
</html>
```

I want to redirect to home.jsp when the user enters correct login details. when the user enters wrong login details then it should stay on the same page and clear the text boxes. i tried a lot of stuff but its not working. please help!

Comment: Google the terms, `requestdispatcher in jsp`

Comment: do not use scriptlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it is a jsp page you can use `response.sendRedirect()`
**note** do not use scriplets in jsp page.Better alternate **jstl**/**el**

If both the form and the jdbc code you have written are in the same page then code part that you are using for checking password will not work because `request.getParameter("usr");` and `request.getParameter("pwd");` will always give `null`

Answer (score 1):

well you can use

```
<%
    String redirectURL = "/Home.jsp";
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
%>
```

but i sincerely suggest using form in your first jsp , submitting the form and then passing it to another JSP

```
    <form action="/Home.jsp">
<!-- keep form elements here -->
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: i was using the second one till now. just wanted to try something new. so i thought of integrating the first two files.
thanx! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have muliple options like [requestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) and [sendRediect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)

```
 if(rs1.getString(1).equals(Password))
    {
        response.sendRedirect("URL")
      }
```

And i will recommend you not to have a java code inside jsp